# Functions as arguments of variadic templates

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

Suppose we have a class

```
template <int(*F)(int, int)>
class A {
    // ...
};
```

It takes a function as a template argument.

Now I want to make a variadic template, which takes functions as template parameters.

```
template <int(*F...)(int, int)> // this won't compile
template <int(*F)(int, int)...> // this won't compile either
```

How to do it properly?

Comment: So what compile errors did you get?

Comment: The ellipsis is always "just before" the name, in this case `F`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
template <int(*...F)(int, int)>
class A {
    // ...
};
```

Answer (score 18):

You may do

```
using Function_t = int(*)(int, int);

template <Function_t ... Fs> struct s{};
```

else, if you don't want to use typedef

```
template <int(*...Fs)(int, int)> struct s{};
```

**Note**: the second version can't be anonymous (`Fs` is required) as ISO C++11 requires a parenthesized pack declaration to have a name.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use F as a template argument.
This not only allows you to use function as parameter but also other types that implements the parenthesis operator.
These classes are called *functors*.

Comment: Might be a wise suggestion but not a solution to the problem. Also note that here, the functions themselves are the template parameters, not just their type. In your case, the functor's types would be the template parameters, but (depending on where they're used) you need to pass them as function arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Function pointer type syntax is annoying.  So code around it:

```
template<class T> using type=T;

template< type<int(int,int)>* ... Fs >
class A {
};
```

Comment: Although interesting, the usage of different syntaxes for those type functions looks weird IMHO. Maybe `pointer<int(int,int)>`?

Comment: @dyp I want things to read left-to-right like "normal" variables, and `pointer<int(int,int)>` doesn't do that.

Comment: Well you could start declaring normal variables like this: `pointer<int> x; array<double, 10> f; reference<array<10, pointer<constant<string>>>> s;` ;) -- hmm named type operators?

Comment: @dyp If we didn't need the closing `>` I'd be more tempted, but prefix-with-closing-brackets is really annoying to work with, as noted by your `>>>>`.  That is one of the reasons why I find too many chained function calls to be annoying, while doing the same with infix operators is not.  Unfortunately, we don't have any syntactic sugar that makes templates prettier.